# Trying to get property of non-object error with laravel blade foreach

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I have a `Trying to get property of non-object` error which I just can't seem to solve. In my view I have a `@foreach`, using relationship tables. The relationships seems to be fine when I check them. The are also no null values in my banks table. I have a user principles table, banks table that I used as relationships to the banking accounts table. With the user principles I do not use a `@foreach` and data displays `{{ $bankAcc->userprinciple->principle }}` correctly.

Here is my Bank Account Model (the relationship with banks):

```
public function banks(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Banks', 'bank_detail_id');
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
public function edit($id){
    $bankAcc = BankingAccount::where('id', $id)->with('userprinciple')->with('banks')->first();
    return view('admin.administration.banking.accounts.edit', compact('bankAcc'));
}
```

My view:

```
<select class="form-control" name="name_of_bank">
    @foreach($bankAcc->banks as $bankA)
        <option value="{{ $bankA->id }}">{{ $bankA->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: @raina77ow, nope tried that -  still same error

Comment: @raina77ow - what else can I use instead of compact?

Comment: can you dump the result `$bankAcc->banks`

Comment: @fayis003

`
Banks {#1107 ▼
  #fillable: array:5 [▶]
  #table: "bank_details"
  +timestamps: true
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:9 [▶]
  #original: array:9 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #forceDeleting: false
}
`

Comment: it's clear that your getting a single model from the result of belongsTo relation that's why the loop is not working

Comment: @fayis003 - okay so the problem is in my model? So must the model be different?

Comment: i think problem is with your relationship what is the relation between bank and bank-account ? and please make use of standard  laravel fundamentals i.e model name must be singular

Answer (score 0):

### Try This

```
<select class="form-control" name="name_of_bank">
        @foreach($bankAcc['banks'] as $bankA)
          <option value="{{ $bankA['id'] }}">{{ $bankA['name'] }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
```

Comment: The error is gone now and my page displays - but the select fields are empty

Comment: Use dd($bankAcc['banks']) to get array response and check the values

Comment: `Banks {#1107 ▼
  #fillable: array:5 [▶]
  #table: "bank_details"
  +timestamps: true
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:9 [▶]
  #original: array:9 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #forceDeleting: false
}`

Answer (score 0):

try dump the result `$bankAcc->banks` and if your getting an eloquent collection then below code will fix the issue

```
<select class="form-control" name="name_of_bank">
    @foreach($bankAcc->banks as $bankA)
         @if($bankA)
            <option value="{{ $bankA->id }}">{{ $bankA->name }}</option>
         @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

if your getting a single model then you dont need a loop

Comment: I think my model is the problem - how to fix if I don't want to get a single model?

Comment: you can do either of two patches (1) change `return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Banks', 'bank_detail_id');` to `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Banks', 'bank_detail_id');` (2) or change `@foreach($bankAcc->banks as $bankA)` to `@foreach($bankAcc->banks()->get() as $bankA)`